# comparing the entries of two arrays

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, array

i am trying to compare the elements of two arrays before the code goes on to the next sequence. The elements of note[x] are filled with the note values of a song. and i want to be able to input values from a midi controller into learn[x]. how can i compare array learn[ ]  to array note[ ] before the showsequence(); is incremented?

```
 const int x = 100;
    int note[x];
    int learn[x];
    int largestindex = 0;
    int learnindex=0;
    void showsequence();
    void readsequnce();
    const int PLAY = 1;
    const int TRYAGIN = 2;
    int state=0;

 void loop() {
     if (state == PLAY) {
        showsequence();
        readsequnce();
      }
      else if (state == TRYAGIN) {
        incorrect();
       }
     MIDI.read();
    }
    void MyHandleNoteOn(byte channel, byte pitch, byte velocity) {
    learn[learnindex]=pitch;
     learnindex++;
    }

 void showsequence() {
      //Add a new index to the end of the songseq
      SongSeq[largestindex];
      largestindex++;
      //loop through the songseq
      for (int index = 0; index < largestindex; index++) {
        SongSeq[index]();
      }
    }

      void readsequnce() {
      static uint16_t nextkey;
      bool mademistake = false;
       nextkey=0;
       learnindex=0;

       if (array_cmp(learn, note, largestindex, largestindex) == true){
               // do this if they are equal
               lcd.setCursor(16, 2);
        lcd.print("True");
         }else{
               // do this if they are different
               lcd.setCursor(16, 2);
        lcd.print("False");
         }
    }

 boolean array_cmp(int *a, int *b, int len_a, int len_b){
         int n;

         // if their lengths are different, return false
         if (len_a != len_b) return false;

         // test each element to be the same. if not, return false
         for (n=0;n<len_a;n++) if (a[n]!=b[n]) return false;

         //ok, if we have not returned yet, they are equal :)
         return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what sort of comparison you want to do.  If you want to see if `note[x] == learn[x]` then that's what you do.

If you want to see if all the notes match all of learn then you'll need to put the comparison in a loop.

```
for (int n = 0; n < MAX_NOTE && note[n] == learn[n]; ++n)
{
    // Empty loop
}
```

If you want to see if the first n notes match the current note and the proceeding n notes then its a bit more complex, but its just a loop.

```
int n = 0;
for (int l = currentPos;
(l > (currentPos - 10)) && (note[n] == learn[l]);
 l--, n++)
{
    // Empty loop
}
```

If it is something else you want, please can you try and describe it in idiot proof terms so I can understand it.

Comment: i want to compare note[x] == learn[x] but then once the compare is matches to compare note[x] == learn[x] (x going from 0->1) increasing  by 1 every time the match is correct

Comment: Then use the bottom example, but `int n = x`, `int l = x` and `l++`.  You will have to be careful about n and l exceeding the maximum index of the array/data, so add two extra conditions into the third line `&& n < maxData && l < maxData`  (Need to set maxData to something sensible.

Answer (score 1):

Start by assuming they match. Loop over each element pair, compare them, and set a flag when you find a pair that don't match.

```
bool they_match = true; // assume they match 
for ( int i = 0; i < x; i++ ) { // for each note/learn element
  if ( note[i] != learn[i] ) { // check if they don't match
    they_match = false; // they don't mach, so set flag
    break; // stop looping 
  }
}
```

At the end `they_match` will be `true` if note[] and learn[] match, or `false` if they don't.

I would suggest you learn how control structures work. 
https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/c++/notes/control1.html
https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/c++/notes/control2.html